# update table column of every row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have a table in sql which has 3 columns named `id`,`title` and `story_url`.

I am trying to make `SEO friendly URL`s. so what I am trying to do is using `title` and `replace` the `white spaces` and `special chars` with dash(-) and save it into other column `story_url`. story_url is empty atm.

Update all my table rows or insert that created url in `story_url`.

If I do it inside while loop then it only adds one last value in all rows.

```
function seoUrl($string) {

    $string = strtolower($string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    $title = $row['title'];
    $story = $row['story'];
    $id = $row['id'];

    $url = seoUrl($title);
    $query = "UPDATE table SET story_url='$url'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
```

Comment: Probably because you dont set `$url` anywhere. Presumably you intended to call `seoUrl()` and use the result?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you cannot miss or ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` query needs to have `WHERE` clause.

Replace your query with below:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET story_url='$url' WHERE id='$id'";
```